# Floor casting algorithm just doing weird things

Tags: c, algorithm, game-development, raycasting

I'm actually using the algorithme of Toto Briac from [Raycaster, searching for more effective floor/ceiling raycast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66670372/raycaster-searching-for-more-effective-floor-ceiling-raycast)
When using it, the floor casting is working well for east and west side, but for north and south it just does weird things (just look image).

```
    double pixelsToBottom;
double pixelsToMid;
double directDistFloor;
double realDistance;
double y;
t_point f_p;

pixelsToBottom = (double)data->s_height - wall[1].y;
pixelsToMid = (double)data->s_height / 2 - pixelsToBottom;
for (int i = pixelsToMid; i < data->s_height / 2; i += 1)
{
    directDistFloor = (data->dist_proj * (double)(data->s_height / 2)) / i;
    realDistance = directDistFloor / fabs(cos(angle));
    f_p.x = data->player.pos.x + cos(angle) * (realDistance) / (data->dist_proj / (64.0));
    f_p.y = data->player.pos.y + sin(angle) * (realDistance) / (data->dist_proj / (64.0));
    y = (wall->x + (i + data->s_height / 2) * data->s_width) / data->s_width;
    pixel_put(&data->obj, wall->x, y, f_pixel(data, f_p));
}
```

But i'm facing an issu, when i'm facing north and south side it's all ok, but when the ray is going into east or west side, the texture just do a weird thing like that :

I know that it refer to : realDistance = directDistFloor / fabs(cos(angle));
if i replace the cos(angle) by sin(angle) in this line, it just invert things. I didn't find a way to change the calcule in right moment. I you have any idea I will take it ! Thank you !!

[image: When facing north or south side]

Comment: Why exactly do you divide by the `fabs(cos(angle))`? In the following lines, you are multiplying by the `cos(angle)` and `sin(angle)` respectively, this does not look quite correct. How does the result look if you do not do the division?

Comment: I divide by the `fabs(cos(angle))` to avoid the fisheye effect. If i don't divid directDistFloor, all the side work properly, there isn't this huge deep effect but the floor is hardly rounded. the `cos(angle)` and `sin(angle)` are used to get the properly texture, if i remove them there is juste huge green line instead off all pixel of the texture. the `directDistFloor` variable is the brut real distance from player to the floor coordinate i'm working on (which decrease with the for). So I have to divided it with `cos(angle)` to applicate the angle of the ray. Thank's for your reply man !

Comment: see [Ray Casting with different height size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47251071/2521214) for some inspiration

Answer (score 2):

It's okay I found the answer, for the people who are interest, in the line   `realDistance = directDistFloor / fabs(cos(angle));` I was using the angle of the ray in the world, I changed it by the angle relative to my player dir (so 0° if it's the player dir ray) and it work properly ! Thank's @ZwergofPhoenix for the time you took !